# Where does PresentationTraceSources.Refresh look for the app.config file?

Tags: wpf, debugging, app-config, trace

I am trying to better understand PresentationTraceSources. The docs for the Refresh() method say "Refreshes trace sources, by forcing the app.config file to be re-read." Where does it expect to find the app.config file? If I add an application configuration file to my project, it is placed in the project source folder, but when the app is deployed, there is no such folder. What does Refresh() do if it can't find app.config. If I configure PresentationTraceSources in code, an app.config file doesn't necessarily exist. But the PresentationTraceSources.Refresh() call is still required. What is really happening in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Systems.Diagnostics listeners without a config file.  In, say, an event handler behind a button, create a listener and then register that listener to the various sources.

The expected scenario is to use a config file, the assumption is that a machine administrator, separate from the user will collect trace and will need to do so without recompile and will need to turn the trace off without recompile. That would be done by configuring the listeners in an app config file, named something like XamlPad.exe.config

And it looks like you need to set a registry key and you need to have full trust.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.aspx

I imagine that this trace is written by MS developers to help you figure out what their code is doing. The System.Net and the WCF stack both use System.Diagnostics trace a lot-- once you know the trace source names you can hook up listeners and "see the matrix" scroll by.

You can write to any trace source, but you'd probably want to create your own trace source, they're easy to create.

Comment: WPF traces can be enabled by setting a flag in registry, or by calling `PresentationTraceSources.Refresh()` from code. See this MSDN [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/14/wpftracesources.aspx)